# Is it possible to debug vc release program with source code in other debugger, such as ollydbg, windbg?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need to watch over the assembly code that vc generated.

Is it possible to debug vc release program with source code in other debugger, such as ollydbg, windbg?

Comment: Do you have a .pdb file for the release build?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes, I have the source code, could you show me how within WinDbg.

Comment: You do know that the compiler can [generate list files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(v=vs.100).aspx) with source code and assembly, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, debuggers like ollydbg or windbg can debug\disassemble\launch every kind of native executables (PE as well), no matter which compiler and which language has been used. 
The only problem is that you won't have much debug symbols and it'll be pretty hard to know where you are and what you are doing.

If a pdb is available, use it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database.